# Move child DIV outside parent DIV

Tags: html, css, css-position

I will go straight to the point. I have a child div that has width of 100% and it is located under wrapper that has a fixed width.I was wondering how can i make the child div "break out" and have 100% full screen page width. Code goes like this, i tried playing with relative/absolute positioning but no luck.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  ...Some other code...
    <div class="banners">
        <div class="first"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></div>
        <div class="second"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></div>
    </div>
   ...Some other code...
</div>
```

Fiddle can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/qMYQw/

Beside "banners" div, there are few more sections both above and bellow that div, thats the reason it "banners" are in wrapper

P.S There are other sections above/bellow the banner DIV, so simply setting up the position:absolute doesnt do the trick

Comment: you have to use `position:absolute` to out of the flow..

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/qMYQw/4/)

```
.banners img {  
    width:100%;
}

.banners .first, .banners .second {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    border:1px solid blue;
}

.banners .second {
    margin-left: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute` only on the `.banners` div and it should do the trick. Note that you'll also need to set `left: 0`.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qMYQw/3/

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:absolute` for your banner.

```
.banners{position:absolute; left:0; width:100%;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qMYQw/5/)

Comment: I know about that, but beside the "banner" DIV, there is more section both above/bellow that section, so setting the position only overlaps over them.

Comment: top of the banners div will not have any issues. Only issue with the bottom of the div. In that case you have to mentioned explicitly the height of banner as margin top to the bottom of the div. check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qMYQw/7/

Comment: True, but i cant declare the height for the banner div because the site is responsive and it would looks weird on smaller resolutions.

http://goo.gl/IDxE5b is the site, 3 boxes at the bottom, you will see what i mean

Answer (score 0):

**Place this in ypur css and see result:** [Here is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qMYQw/6/)

```
.wrapper {
    width:500px;
    height:600px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:1px solid red;

}
.banners img {
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid blue;

}
.banners .first, .banners .second {
    float:left;
    width:49%;
    height:1200px;
    border:1px solid GREEN;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is to take your `banners` div out of the wrapper and restart a new wrapper after the `banners` div

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/qMYQw/10/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper"></div>

<div class="banners">
    <div class="first">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    width:500px; /* or whatever */
    height:200px; /* demo height only */
    margin:0 auto;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.banners {
    overflow: hidden; /* quick clearfix */
}
.banners img {
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
.banners .first, .banners .second {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use z-index

```
.wrapper {
    z-index : 1
}

.banners {
    position : absolute;
    left : 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like the way your HTML is structured, you can simply **tell the banners to be 2x larger** and let the images fill the rest of the space.

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.banners { 
    width: 200%;
    margin-left: -50%; 
}
.banners .first, 
.banners .second {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
.banners img {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="banners">
        <div class="first"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
        <div class="second"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```