# How to call custom filter from an external control in ag-grid-ng2?

Tags: angular, gridview, filter, datagrid, ag-grid

I want to have custom dropdown listboxes with the options from the `ag-grid` filter control outside of the `ag-grid` table.

I need this for touch devices where I want to have the filter control always visible and with more touch-compatible dimensions.

How to get the overlay of the internal `ag-grid` header filter icon click to expand on a custom markup element outside of `ag-grid`?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You can manipulate the css to do this. Would be even easier if you have created a custom filter too. You can try w/ this approach as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24927910/move-child-div-outside-parent-div